# Error in persian language in canvas

Tags: canvas, persian

[image]

When I want to convert html code to image with canvas I have a problem.

This is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
 font-family: "omid";
 src: url(BYekan.eot);
 src: url(../Fonts/BYekan.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../Fonts/BYekan.woff) format("woff"), url(BYekan.ttf) format("truetype"), url(../Fonts/Yekan.svg#BYekan) format("svg");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myCanvas" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: right;">
        <strong>Codepedia.info</strong><hr/>
        <h3 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Html to canvas, and canvas to proper image
        </h3>
        <p  style="color: #3e4b51; font-family:omid;">
            <b>Codepedia.info</b>حامد سلامی. Tutorials focused on Programming ASP.Net,
            C#, jQuery, AngularJs, Gridview, MVC, Ajax, Javascript, XML, MS SQL-Server, NodeJs,
            Web Design, Software</p>
        <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
            <b>html2canvas</b> script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts
            of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as
            such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation.
        </p>
    </div>
    <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function(){

 
var element = $("#myCanvas"); // global variable

var getCanvas; // global variable
 
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

 $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
 });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I can't read persian but is this only a font issue?